# What is an antonym for mnemonic?

Tags: single-word-requests

The English language has evolved in such a way that it seems to undercut itself. For example, the large number of irregular verbs. It’s almost as though the language wants its speakers to forget that it has rules, and many habitually do. If someone deliberately created a language (or any system, for that matter) that deliberately used a device to make its speakers forget its rules, in other words an antonym of mnemonic [“... a device for assisting memory...” M-W. ], what would that device be called?

Comment: *Oblivion*.....?

Comment: If someone were to invent a sport that involved spinning in circles while wearing purple shorts and red eyeliner what would it be called?... You're making a word request for a concept that you've just invented.

Comment: Along the same line as Josh61...is the *"obliviate"* charm used in Harry Potter stories to cause someone to lose their memories. :-)

Comment: Brainwashing was a technique used in espionage and war, supposedly, to induce someone to forget particular memories of their actions or certain events.

Comment: You can use *Lethe* figuratively. In Greek mythology, it is the name of a river and anyone who drank from it experienced complete forgetfulness. In Ancient Greek, Λήθη (Lḗthē) means forgetfulness.

Comment: @DaveMagner That's obviously crazy. No one would match eyeliner and pants color like that.

Comment: An *obluiette* is a *device designed to make people forget*, but it's a real-world object, not a rhetorical device, and it's designed to make people forget whatever it contains, as opposed to the device itself or "the rules".

Comment: @DanBron: Isn't it a type of dungeon? [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dungeon) says: "The word comes from the same root as the French oublier, "to forget", as it was used for those prisoners the captors wished to forget."

Comment: @ermanen Yes, that's what I just said: *a real-world object designed to make people forget its contents*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, as Dave says, it is making a word request for a concept that OP has just invented.

Comment: I very much like the suggested words. Obluiette comes very close to what I'm seeking. I imagine that Rowling coined obliviate, but it's a sensible word. I had forgotten about Lethe. "Let's put a Lethe into the system," sounds intriguing. Brainwashing might be difficult. The sport is called figure skating.

Comment: The question boils down to "What is an antonym for mnemonic?"  What's off-topic about that? I didn't invent mnemonic and I didn't invent antonym. I provided a context for the use of the answer, that's all.

Comment: Yeah, there is one, but I can never remember what it is.

Answer (score 1):

If [mnemonic](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/mnemonic) is a memory aid, a memory block like [amnesia](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/amnesia)  would be the opposite.